# Tomcat rewrite URL for basic authentication

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to re-write a URL in Tomcat 8.  I have the Valve set up correctly as I have tested the following to forward (by re-writing) my root URL to my geoserver URL:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) /geoserver/web/ [R]
```

Great, but what I want to do is a bit more complex and I'm having trouble working out how.  Embedded in the URL will be a user name and password along the lines of:

```
https://my-url.com/some_stuff?PW=123?UN=456
```

I wish to simply convert this by re-writing the URL to:

```
https://123:456@www.my-url.com/some_stuff
```

This is so that my basic authentication will work on my Geoserver.

Any steps in the right direction would be really appreciated